# Laravel - Avoid validation error for unique rule when updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3's validation as follows:

In my model:

```
public static $validation = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'username' => 'required|alpha|unique:companies',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:companies',
];
```

In my controller, I post to the same `CompanyController@dataPost` method when creating a new item or when editing one:

```
public function dataPost(Request $request) {

    // First validation
    $this->validate($request, Company::$validation);

    $id = $request->id;

    if ($id > 0) {
        // Is an edit!
        $company = Company::find($id);
        $company->update($request->all());
        $company->save();

        Session::flash('messageclass', 'success');
        Session::flash('message', trans('companies.editedsuccessfully'));

    } else {
        // Is a create
        $company = new Company($request->all());
        $company->save();

        Session::flash('messageclass', 'success');
        Session::flash('message', trans('companies.createdsuccessfully'));
    }

    return redirect()->route('companyindex');
}
```

The unique validation works ok when I create a new item, but causes an error (as in it flags the username as already existing) when editing an item.

Any idea how to avoid this? Even in an edit I'd still want to ensure the data is unique if it's changed, but if the value is the same as before then ignore the validation.

I know I could do this manually, but I wonder if there is a built-in way to avoid this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this:

```
public static $validation = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email'     => Auth::check()
                ? 'required|email|unique:companies,email,'.Auth::id()
                : 'required|email|unique:companies,email',
    'username'  => Auth::check()
                ? 'required|alpha|unique:companies,username,'.Auth::id()
                : 'required|alpha|unique:companies,username',
];
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand correctly, this would cause the `unique` rule to be ignored for the current user's id. Will this stop me from changing my email to an existing user's email?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Passing id makes Laravel ignore your updating user while looking for stored / duplicated values.

Comment: @zundi: Hope, My answer is your solution and it's work fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can update `email` field with unique property as well.

Following rule will check uniqueness among all emails in other column except current one.

Try this one,

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . $userId
```

here `$userId` refers to `id` of user currently updated.

You can see official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

You can create different validation methods for `insert` or `update`

```
public static $validation_update = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'username' => 'required|alpha',
    'email' => 'required|email',
];

public static $validation_add = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'username' => 'required|alpha|unique:companies',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:companies',
];
```

Then apply validation in condition

```
public function dataPost(Request $request) {

    // First validation


    $id = $request->id;

    if ($id > 0) {
        // Is an edit!
      $this->validate($request, Company::$validation_update);
        $company = Company::find($id);
        $company->update($request->all());
        $company->save();

        Session::flash('messageclass', 'success');
        Session::flash('message', trans('companies.editedsuccessfully'));

    } else {
        // Is a create
      $this->validate($request, Company::$validation_add);
        $company = new Company($request->all());
        $company->save();

        Session::flash('messageclass', 'success');
        Session::flash('message', trans('companies.createdsuccessfully'));
    }

    return redirect()->route('companyindex');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the standard practice for this scenario?

Comment: One thing you're missing is if during an update I (for example) change the username to one that already exists.

Comment: @zundi better way to avoid updation for `username`

Answer (score -2):

$id = $request->id;

```
if ($id > 0) {
    // Is an edit!
  $this->validate($request, Company::$validation_update);
    $company = Company::find($id);
    $company->update($request->all());
    $company->save();
```